# Why isn't OnActivate being called?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm asking this here because I'm at a loss for trying to figure this out. I've searched and all that comes up are things that make sense but also don't apply to my situation.

I'm using `WPF` with `MVVM` and `Caliburn.Micro`. I have a shell window with a corresponding view model which is a `Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OnceActive` and a screen which is inheriting from `Screen`. I'm calling `ActivateItem` within the Conductor's constructor to show the subsequent screen, it shows the screen correctly but never calls the Screen's override for `OnActivate` and the screen's `IsActive` property is set to `False`.

This only happens the very first time I call `ActivateItem` from the Conductor, all additional calls will properly call `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate`.

This makes no sense to me and I have no idea what is going on. I cleaned the solution, rebuilt, and even rebooted but it still doesn't work properly. Below is the code:

**Parent Conductor**

```
[Export]
public sealed class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<SimpleMessage>
{
    private readonly DashboardViewModel m_Dash;
    private readonly LoginViewModel m_Login;
    private readonly IEventAggregator m_MsgBus;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(DashboardViewModel dash, LoginViewModel login, IEventAggregator msgBus)
    {
        this.m_MsgBus = msgBus;
        this.m_Dash = dash;
        this.m_Login = login;

        this.ActivateItem(this.m_Login);
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        this.m_MsgBus.Subscribe(this); //called correctly
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        this.m_MsgBus.Unsubscribe(this); //called correctly
    }

    public void Handle(SimpleMessage message)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case SimpleMessage.LoginSuccess:
                this.ActivateItem(this.m_Dash);
                break;

            case SimpleMessage.Logout:
                this.ActivateItem(this.m_Login);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Child Screen**

```
[Export]
public sealed class LoginViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator m_MsgBus;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator msgBus)
    {
        this.m_MsgBus = msgBus;
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        //NOT called the first time, but is called every other time
        MessageBox.Show("ACTIVATE TEST");
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        //NOT called the first time, but is called every other time
        MessageBox.Show("DEACTIVATE TEST");
    }

    public void CmdLogin(string password)
    {
        this.m_MsgBus.PublishOnUIThread(SimpleMessage.LoginSuccess);
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I downloaded the Caliburn Micro source so I could step into the `ActivateItem` function and see what is going on. For some reason, when I first call `ActivateItem` from the Conductor the Conductor's `IsActive` property is set to false which causes Caliburn to skip calling the `OnActivate` override. I have no idea why the property would be false.

**ConductorBaseWithActiveItem.cs**

```
protected virtual void ChangeActiveItem(T newItem, bool closePrevious) {
    ScreenExtensions.TryDeactivate(activeItem, closePrevious);

    newItem = EnsureItem(newItem);

    //Problem is here, IsActive is false the first time around in the conductor
    if(IsActive)
        ScreenExtensions.TryActivate(newItem);

    activeItem = newItem;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange("ActiveItem");
    OnActivationProcessed(activeItem, true);
}
```

It looks like the reason `IsActive` is false in the Conductor is because my Conductor is the root view which is created using `DisplayRootViewFor` and it looks like that function does not set the `IsActive` property to true.

So, knowing that, am I simply just implementing this wrong and a Conductor can't/shouldn't be the root view? Do I need to have a 2nd child view which is the conductor (that seems like a bit much)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out and it was basically me not thinking. Activating a view in the constructor of the conductor/root view doesn't work properly because it hasn't been activated yet. `IsActive` isn't set to true until the conductor's/root view's `OnActivate` is called.

This may be problematic at some point because the conductor isn't active even when `OnInitialize` is called and that is meant to be the one time init function and `OnActivate` could be called multiple times. In my case it will be fine because my conductor is the root view so `OnActivate` will only be called once.

Moral of the story is, don't call `ActivateItem` in a conductor's constructor when the conductor is a root view.

Comment: I struggled with this too until I found your answer. That was last week. Today I was researching something else and found this behaviour is mentioned specifically in the documentation at http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition:
> If you activate an item in a conductor that is itself not active, that item won’t actually be activated until the conductor gets activated.