# ViewModel won't handle a EventAggregator event

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I only seem to be able to handle EventAggregator events from the `ShellViewModel`, but I want to handle it from `LoginViewModel`.

The `ShellViewModel` constructs `LoginViewModel` as it's Active Item. I've also set it up to inherit from `IHandle<AuthenticatedMessage>` as a test that event publishing is working. It is able to handle that event. I haven't shown any Unsubscribe events in my code for brevity.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<AuthenticatedMessage>    
{
    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _loginViewModel = loginViewModel;
    }
    
    protected override async Task OnActivateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.OnActivateAsync(cancellationToken);
        _eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this);
    
        await ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel);
    }
    
    public async Task HandleAsync(AuthenticatedMessage authCode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // this is reached! So the event is publishing successfully.
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

`LoginViewModel` also subscribes to this event, but it's Handle method is not invoked.

The `Login` method is responsible for creating the `LoginWindowViewModel` Window (shown underneath) which publishes the event.

```
public class LoginViewModel : Screen, IHandle<AuthenticatedMessage>
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
    private readonly ILoginWindowViewModelFactory _LoginWindowViewModelFactory;

    public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, 
        IWindowManager windowManager, 
        ILoginWindowViewModelFactory loginWindowViewModelFactory)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator; 
        _windowManager = windowManager;
        _LoginWindowViewModelFactory = loginWindowViewModelFactory;
    }
    
    protected override async Task OnActivateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.OnActivateAsync(cancellationToken);
        
        _eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this);
    }
    
    // This is bound to a button click event. It creates a window.
    public async void Login()
    {
        Uri loginUri = new Uri(_api.BaseLoginUrl);

        await _windowManager.ShowWindowAsync(
            _ndLoginWindowViewModelFactory.Create(loginUri, _eventAggregator));
    }       
    
    
    public async Task HandleAsync(AuthenticatedMessage authCode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // why is this is never reached?
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The `LoginWindowViewModel` that publishes a `AuthenticatedMessage` event:

```
public class LoginWindowViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly Uri _initialUri;         

    public NDLoginWindowViewModel(Uri initialUri, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _initialUri = initialUri;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }       
    
    // bound to the WebView2 (browser control) event
    public async void NavigationStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
    {            
            string authCode = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(e.Uri).Query).Get("code");
            
            // Publish event here. LoginViewModel should handle this, but currently only ShellViewModel can.
            await _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new AuthenticatedMessage(authCode));                              
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue after moving `eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this);` to the `LoginViewModel` constructor, instead of the `OnActivateAsync()` method.

From here:

```
protected override async Task OnActivateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await base.OnActivateAsync(cancellationToken);
    
    _eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this);
}
```

To here:

```
public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, 
    IWindowManager windowManager, 
    ILoginWindowViewModelFactory loginWindowViewModelFactory)
{
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator; 
    _windowManager = windowManager;
    _LoginWindowViewModelFactory = loginWindowViewModelFactory;

    _eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this);
}
```

EDIT:

The `OnActivateAsync` method isn't being called when the View is first created in the `ShellViewModel` because it is my root Screen and Conductor. So the Subscription was never taking place.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
...
    protected override async Task OnActivateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.OnActivateAsync(cancellationToken);            
    
        await ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel);
        // IsActive = false here, therefore the child Screen `_loginViewModel` 
        // is also not active. Result is that OnActivateAsync 
        // in this view model does not get called.
    }
}
```

It is directly related to [this problem and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019227/why-isnt-onactivate-being-called).

That explains why moving it to the constructor solved the problem.

The final solution was to add `_eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this);` in both the Constructor AND `OnActivateAsync` method. This allows me to resubscribe to the event after I navigate away from this viewmodel and come back to it.

Comment: I'm calling _eventAggregator.SubscribeOnPublishedThread(this); in OnActivateAsync before await base.OnActivateAsync(cancellationToken);, so, maybe it's another way how to fix it

Comment: Yep you're right, found out more info. OnActivateAsync was never being called because of the way I activated the view  model in the root ShellViewModel.